# My search input functions works, but it only prints the last person's information in the list of dicts

Tags: python, dictionary, search, printing, conditional-statements

I'm kind of new to python, and I need some help. I'm making an employee list menu. My list of dictionaries is:

```
person_infos = [ {'name': 'John Doe', 'age': '46', 'job position': 'Chair Builder', 'pay per hour': '14.96','date hired': '2/26/19'},

  {'name': 'Phillip Waltertower', 'age': '19', 'job position': 'Sign Holder', 'pay per hour': '10','date hired': '5/9/19'},

  {'name': 'Karen Johnson', 'age': '40', 'job position': 'Manager', 'pay per hour': '100','date hired': '9/10/01'},

  {'name': 'Linda Bledsoe', 'age': '60', 'job position': 'CEO', 'pay per hour': '700', 'date hired': '8/24/99'},

  {'name': 'Beto Aretz', 'age': '22', 'job position': 'Social Media Manager', 'pay per hour': '49','date hired': '2/18/12'}]
```

and my "search the list of dicts input function" is how the program is supposed to print the correct dictionary based on the name the user inputs:

```
def search_query(person_infos):
  if answer == '3':
    search_query = input('Who would you like to find: ')
    they_are_found = False
    location = None
    for i, each_employee in enumerate(person_infos):
      if each_employee['name'] == search_query:
        they_are_found = True
      location = i
    if they_are_found:
      print('Found: ', person_infos[location]['name'], person_infos[location]['job position'], person_infos[location]['date hired'], person_infos[location]['pay per hour'])
  else:
      print('Sorry, your search query is non-existent.')
```

and I also have this-

```
elif answer =='3':
  person_infos = search_query(person_infos)
```

This seems like a step in the right direction, but for

```
search_query = input('Who would you like to find: ')
```

if I input of the names in `person_infos`, like "John Doe," it just prints the last dictionary's information (no matter which specific dictionary it is, the last one in the order will always be outputted) instead of John Doe's. in this case, it would only print "Beto Aretz's."
Can someone please help? It's something I've been struggling on for a while and it would be awesome.
I've researched so much and I could not find something with things that I either knew how to do, or were the input search.

Thanks,
LR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance it looks like because your `location=i` is not indented inside your if statement so it is getting set to the latest `i` on each iteration of the for loop. Let me know if this helps.

```
def search_query(person_infos):
  if answer == '3':
    search_query = input('Who would you like to find: ')
    they_are_found = False
    location = None
    for i, each_employee in enumerate(person_infos):
      if each_employee['name'] == search_query:
        they_are_found = True
        location = i
    if they_are_found:
      print('Found: ', person_infos[location]['name'], person_infos[location]['job position'], person_infos[location]['date hired'], person_infos[location]['pay per hour'])
  else:
      print('Sorry, your search query is non-existent.')
```